# cannot find the data from mongodb/mongoose in next js

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, next.js, nextjs-dynamic-routing

hey i'm trying to fetch the multiple data from mongodb in mongoose with different id's but i get unkown error i try few different different approach but nothing works for me

**fetcing the data**

```
 let ids = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < itemforbuy.length; i++) {
    ids.push(itemforbuy[i]._id);
  }
  let fetchingRemove = await fetch(
    `${process.env.HOSTING_NAME}/api/removeProductQty`,
    {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        orderId: ids,
      }),
    }
  );
  let response = await fetchingRemove.json();
  console.log(response);
```

**api**

```
import connectDb from "../../middleware/mongoose";
import Product from "../../modals/Product";

const handler = async (req, res) => {
   console.log("body", req.body.orderId);
   let orderId = req.body.orderId;
   console.log(orderId);
   let products = await Product.find().where("_id").in(orderId).exec();
   console.log(products);

   res.status(200).json(products);
};
export default connectDb(handler);
```

i tried fetching the data with array **map** **forEach** but nothing works

**the error**
its give empty array but when i hard code the ids like

```
let ids = ["abc","abc","abc"]
```

then it finds the fetch the data. i hope you guys will help me to fix this error

Comment: How does your "Product" Schema look like?